# eclipse selection dialog input is IField[], but return value is Object[] of SourceFields

Tags: eclipse, dialog

i'm display a selection dialog in eclipse (ListSelectionDialog) and the input is a List of IField (org.eclipse.jdt.core.IField). the list is ok, the selection also, but the return value of the dialog offers only a list of object (Object[]) and every object is a SourceField (org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SourceField).

so my question is:
i need the selected fields as IField and a direct cast is unfortunaly not the answer. :(
so how can i get a list of IFields from the SourceFields?

any hints?
thanks a lot!
Sven

Answer (score 0):

`SourceField` implements the `IField` interface so you can cast individual objects:

```
IField [] result = new IField[objectArray.length];
for (int i = 0; i < result.length; ++i) {
   result[i] = (IField)objectArray[i];
}
```

Comment: you're right, i dismissed this. now it worked absolutely fine. thank you again, greg :)